# Camera2 API - Huawei exposure apply in next shoot

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-camera2

I facing an issue with `camera2` API when taking multiple shoots when setting
`CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME`.

I already put `CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE` on `OFF` but the exposure will apply on the next shoot.
has anyone ever had this problem before?

Thanks in Advance.